# Karabiner forward delete how to revert to backslash

Tags: macos, karabiner

I use Karabiner to modify backslash to be forward delete. Works great but if I ever need to type a backslash how do I do that?

Comment: Does the keyboard you are using **not** have a fn key in order to do a fn+Backspace for a Forward Delete?

Comment: Yes but that needs two hands. I much prefer to have a dedicated forward delete like any full size keyboard including my IMac keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of [complex_modifications rules](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=forward%20delete) for forward delete, I installed both [Shift-Delete](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#shift-delete-to-delete-forward) and [Equals + Delete](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#equals_del_to_forward_del)(can be used by one hand).

To use backslash, you need create a customize rule:

- Download the [JSON file of Equals + Delete](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/json/equals_del_to_forward_del.json).
- Edit it with with a plan text editor, remove the block of `delete_or_backspace`, and add replace `equal_sign` with `backslash`.
- Install and [test the rule](https://github.com/pqrs-org/KE-complex_modifications#testing-your-own-rules).

---

The customized JSON file content:

```json
{
    "title": "Equals + Delete to Forward Delete",
    "rules": [
        {
            "description": "Simultaneously press Equals + Del to get a ForwardDel",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "simultaneous": [
                            {
                                "key_code": "backslash"
                            }
                        ],
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "delete_forward"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you figured this out, but I use backslash as forward delete the same way you do, so I wrote this complex mod that maps fn+backslash to backslash as well

```json
    {
    "title": "Backslash to Forward Delete",
    "rules": [
        {
            "description": "Change backslash to forward delete, fn+backslash to backslash",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "backslash",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "delete_forward"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "backslash",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to":   [
                        {
                            "key_code": "backslash"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now if I could just figure out why command+delete_forward doesn't delete to the end of the line...